# Describing a string array in a wsdl file

Tags: java, wsdl, globus-toolkit

I'm using the globus toolkit for a project. In my service i have a resource: a string array. I want to get this resource from an Android client. How can I do that? How can I describe in the wsdl file the type "array of string"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this

```
<complexType name='ArrayOfString'>
    <sequence>
        <element name='item' type='xsd:string' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Source: http://www.activebpel.org/samples/samples-2/BPEL_Samples/Resources/Docs/arrays.html

UPDATE:

I've done a test using NetBeans 7.0.1. The results were this:

Declare a method that receives a String[] parameter:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "helloArray")
public String helloArray(@WebParam(name = "name") String[] name) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello ");
    if (name != null) {
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            sb.append(name[i]);
            if (i < (name.length - 1)) {
                sb.append(" and ");
            }
        }
    }
    sb.append('!');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The WSDL generated a complex type for my method with a String array element

```html
<xs:complexType name="helloArray">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" 
            maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

In the client, the IDE generated a `List<String>` to consume it:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "helloArray", propOrder = {"name"})
public class HelloArray {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<String> name;

    public List<String> getName() {
        if (name == null) {
            name = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And a method to consume the service

```
private String helloArray(java.util.List<java.lang.String> name) {
    edu.home.wsclient.HelloWorldWS port = service.getHelloWorldWSPort();
    return port.helloArray(name);
}
```

I've uploaded both projects [in this address](http://www.2shared.com/file/KB-HOU7P/WSExample.html)

Comment: Thank you. Now when I get the response from the client, as a generic Java object, and I try to cast it to a (String []) I get a ClassCastException.

Comment: I also get an Exception in validating the wsdl: ArrayOfString is referenced but not defined!

Comment: is this in the WSDL or in a XSD file?

Comment: when I call the getClass() method on the response it returns me java.lang.String. I wonder why!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom type which has a String element (and more data, if you'd like) with multiplicity > 1.

```
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="YourClass" type="pre:YourClass" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Comment: How do I cast the Object returned by the response? If I try with (String []) I get a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

Have the XML call out a parent tag with multiple children, each with one string value from your array:

```
<parent>
    <child>String 1</child>
    <child>String 2</child>
</parent>
```

Name the tags appropriately.