# Error in Axis generate webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I've generated a Webservice client using Axis 1. The webservice worked fine at first, but we have some problems with a specific method.

There is a method to retrieve information about one item, and a method to retrieve information about several items. The first method requires a string id of the item, the second method requires a string[] wiht id to the items.

I've googled the problem and found this site which describes the problem we are having: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2669

Unfortunatly I can not tell you which webservice this is about or disclose the wsdl, but I'm hoping there is an Axis expert who can help me find a workaround or fix for this problem, preferably without changes to the webservice server (since this is a third party).

Kind regards,

JohannisK

---------------------- Editted WSDL ---------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>-<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="<url>" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="<url>" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
-<wsdl:types>
-<xsd:schema targetNamespace="<url>">
-<xsd:complexType name="arrayArray">
-<xsd:complexContent>
-<xsd:restriction base="soap-enc:Array"><xsd:attribute wsdl:arrayType="soap-enc:Array[]" ref="soap-enc:arrayType"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:complexContent></xsd:complexType>
-<xsd:complexType name="intArray">
-<xsd:complexContent>
-<xsd:restriction base="soap-enc:Array"><xsd:attribute wsdl:arrayType="xsd:int[]" ref="soap-enc:arrayType"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:complexContent></xsd:complexType>
-<xsd:complexType name="stringArray">
-<xsd:complexContent>
-<xsd:restriction base="soap-enc:Array"><xsd:attribute wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" ref="soap-enc:arrayType"/></xsd:restriction></xsd:complexContent></xsd:complexType></xsd:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="getSyncIdRequest"/>
-<wsdl:message name="getSyncIdResponse"><wsdl:part name="getSyncIdReturn" type="xsd:string"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="sendItemsDataRequest"><wsdl:part name="sId" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr1" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr2" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr3" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr4" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr5" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr6" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr7" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr8" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr9" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr10" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sAttr11" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="aItemsParts" type="tns:arrayArray"/><wsdl:part name="aItemsComments" type="tns:arrayArray"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="sendItemsDataResponse"><wsdl:part name="sendItemsDataReturn" type="tns:arrayArray"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsIDsByChangedStatusRequest"><wsdl:part name="sId" type="xsd:string"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsIDsByChangedStatusResponse"><wsdl:part name="getItemsIDsByChangedStatusReturn" type="tns:arrayArray"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsStatusByIDsRequest"><wsdl:part name="sId" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="aItemsIDs" type="tns:intArray"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsStatusByIDsResponse"><wsdl:part name="getItemsStatusByIDsReturn" type="tns:arrayArray"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsStatusBySendersRefsRequest"><wsdl:part name="sId" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="aSendersRefs" type="tns:stringArray"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsStatusBySendersRefsResponse"><wsdl:part name="getItemsStatusBySendersRefsReturn" type="tns:arrayArray"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsStatusBySendersRefRequest"><wsdl:part name="sId" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="aSendersRef" type="xsd:string"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsStatusBySendersRefResponse"><wsdl:part name="getItemsStatusBySendersRefReturn" type="xsd:int"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsStatusRequest"><wsdl:part name="sId" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="iItemsId" type="xsd:int"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getItemsStatusResponse"><wsdl:part name="getItemsStatusReturn" type="xsd:int"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getExtraInformationRequest"><wsdl:part name="sId" type="xsd:string"/><wsdl:part name="sSendersRef" type="xsd:string"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:message name="getExtraInformationResponse"><wsdl:part name="getExtraInformationReturn" type="tns:arrayArray"/></wsdl:message>
-<wsdl:portType name="portalInterfacePortType">
-<wsdl:operation name="getSyncId"><wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:getSyncIdRequest"/><wsdl:output message="tns:getSyncIdResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="sendItemsData"><wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:sendItemsDataRequest"/><wsdl:output message="tns:sendItemsDataResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsIDsByChangedStatus"><wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:getItemsIDsByChangedStatusRequest"/><wsdl:output message="tns:getItemsIDsByChangedStatusResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsStatusByIDs"><wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:getItemsStatusByIDsRequest"/><wsdl:output message="tns:getItemsStatusByIDsResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsStatusBySendersRefs"><wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:getItemsStatusBySendersRefsRequest"/><wsdl:output message="tns:getItemsStatusBySendersRefsResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsStatusBySendersRef"><wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:getItemsStatusBySendersRefRequest"/><wsdl:output message="tns:getItemsStatusBySendersRefResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsStatus"><wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:getItemsStatusRequest"/><wsdl:output message="tns:getItemsStatusResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getExtraInformation"><wsdl:documentation></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:getExtraInformationRequest"/><wsdl:output message="tns:getExtraInformationResponse"/></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType>
-<wsdl:binding name="portalInterfaceBinding" type="tns:portalInterfacePortType"><soap-env:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
-<wsdl:operation name="getSyncId"><soap-env:operation style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://<url>/service.php?method=getSyncId"/>
-<wsdl:input><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="sendItemsData"><soap-env:operation style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://<url>/service.php?method=sendItemsData"/>
-<wsdl:input><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsIDsByChangedStatus"><soap-env:operation style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://<url>/service.php?method=getItemsIDsByChangedStatus"/>
-<wsdl:input><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsStatusByIDs"><soap-env:operation style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://<url>/service.php?method=getItemsStatusByIDs"/>
-<wsdl:input><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsStatusBySendersRefs"><soap-env:operation style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://<url>/service.php?method=getItemsStatusBySendersRefs"/>
-<wsdl:input><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsStatusBySendersRef"><soap-env:operation style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://<url>/service.php?method=getItemsStatusBySendersRef"/>
-<wsdl:input><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getItemsStatus"><soap-env:operation style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://<url>/service.php?method=getItemsStatus"/>
-<wsdl:input><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
-<wsdl:operation name="getExtraInformation"><soap-env:operation style="rpc" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://<url>/service.php?method=getExtraInformation"/>
-<wsdl:input><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:input>
-<wsdl:output><soap-env:body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="encoded"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding>
-<wsdl:service name="portalInterface"><wsdl:documentation/>
-<wsdl:port name="portalInterfacePort" binding="tns:portalInterfaceBinding"><soap-env:address location="http://<url>/service.php"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

how do you generate your client? do you have a XSD file can you give more information. You can post a similar wsdl or code that does not give any hint of your original wsdl...

Comment: Added a modified WSDL. The problem seems to be Axis itself. If you know good tools to generate a stand alone client (without the use of Axis) sugestions are welcome.

Comment: are you using soap 1.0 or 1.1

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483318/describing-a-string-array-in-a-wsdl-file