# How to pass an array to soap web service in java using axis2?

Tags: java

I have a web service that is developed with soap using axis2 implementaion but my server side needs array as method argument. How to expose an array in soap request?

```
public boolean addOperation(String params[]){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make changes to the Web service WSDL first and then regenerate the Skeleton from the WSDL, like wise the WebService client will have to regenerate Client Stub with new WSDL and use it on the client side.

Example of changes to WSDL:

```
<complexType name='ArrayOfString'>
    <sequence>
        <element name='item' type='xsd:string' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
    </sequence> 
</complexType>
```

This is a similar question [Describing a string array in a wsdl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483318/describing-a-string-array-in-a-wsdl-file)